# Smart contract works on remix and ganache but not on private chain developed by geth

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, truffle

The smart contract works well on the ganache and remix but not work on the private chain, even though i use the --testnet

> geth --identity "EDU" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpc --rpcport "8545"
>   --datadir data --allow-insecure-unlock --port "30303" --rpcapi "miner,debug,personal,db,eth,net,web3" --testnet --nodiscover  console

this is how i start the console

> development: {
>         host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
>         port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
>         network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
>        },

this is the config of my truffle

> pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0; contract Modify {
>       event modified_student(
>           address indexed _from,
>           bytes32 _data
>       );
>       event modified_teacher(
>           address indexed _from,
>           bytes32 _data
>       );
>       event modified_auth(
>           address indexed _from,
>           bytes32 _data
>       );
>       function modify_auth(bytes32 data ) public payable
>       {
>           emit modified_auth(msg.sender, data);
>       }
>       function modify_teacher(bytes32 data ) public payable
>       {
>           emit modified_teacher(msg.sender, data);
>       }
>       function modify_student(bytes32 data ) public payable
>       {
>           emit modified_student(msg.sender, data);
>       } }

this is the smart contract and I use web3 to call the modify_student function

[image]

there suppose to have something in the log but actually it's not. 
I suppose that might be a problem with the gas estimation, the gas estimation seems not work. and no matter how many gas i set for the transaction, it will run out all of them. the contract runs well on remix and ganache. I can not find the reason.

Comment: In the "Truffle/Ganache" configuration, you have 10 unlocked accounts by default. In the "Geth Private Network" configuration, you don't (which means you can't just send the transaction to the node and have it signing the transaction for you; instead, you have to sign the transaction with your private key first, and only then send the signed transaction to the node).

Comment: actually, I unlocked the account, there is no waring or error, and the transaction already be written in to the block, as you can see from the picture, I already have the receipt, but just with an empty log

Comment: BTW, there are better (cleaner, safer for your own personal privacy, easier for the viewer) ways to copy your screen than taking a photo of it with your camera. Put aside those better ways, it is also better for the viewer to get it in plain (copy/pastable) text rather than an image to begin with. In its current state, one cannot easily copy stuff in order to refer to your question. Moreover, that screenshot with your face in the background makes it rather hard to read the text. And hey, all we need here is the text - nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I am sorry for the bothering that the picture makes for you to read. It's not me, it's a famous Japanese actor, I put his picture as the background of my terminal. The screen shot is a receipt I got from the transaction. I think it may not need to be copy and past so I simply take a screenshot. Thank you anyway I will take care of it next time.

Comment: What does your chain genesis file look like? Which version of solc are you using? The most common problem in your same situation is that your private blockchain doesn't have all the opcodes required by solc enabled, ie those that were incoporated in constantinople/petersburg fork.

Comment: I am using geth 1.9.8 and solc 0.5.1. I am using the testnet so I think the genesis file  might not affect, it's the ropsten network with nodiscover mode

Comment: @linerking Ropsten had forked to constantinople at block 4,230,000, if you forked from a previous block it doesn't have new opcodes.

Comment: I never fork the block, i use the nodiscover mode to build my own private chain, does that affect?